# How to add multiple bindings to same dependency property in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Another WPF question for you all.

I have a user control that contains a text box and button.  The button opens a "folder selection" dialog; when the user selects a folder, the text box should populate with the path the user selected.  That works fine.

Inside of the user control, I have a dependency property named Path.  When the user makes their selection, the Path gets updated and the text box bound to it also updates.  That works great.

Now, the parent View also needs to know what this Path value is.  What to do from here?

I'd assume that we should add a property to the parent's view model named Path.  Easy enough -- then what do we bind it to?  The Path dependency property of the user control?  Can that be bound to both the parent's View Model and user control's text box simultaneously?

I tried adding the user controls attributes without success:

`<v:MyControl Path="{Binding ViewModels:MyViewModel.Path}" ... />`

No errors, it just didn't update the view model.  If this approach is feasible, I can post more of the code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Phil.  I added what I tried, but something feels wrong about this approach so I thought I'd ask if this was even a reasonable approach going forward.

Comment: BTW, it's probably not a good idea for your ViewModel's properties to be static. If they are, you're limited to one instance of the viewmodel in a single process. Better to do `<v:MyControl DataContext="{Binding}" Path="{Binding Path"} ... />`, if your parent view's `DataContext` is set to the viewmodel as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency properties can be the source of multiple bindings, yes. Speaking solely about the view, I could have a master slider with five text boxes bound to its value, and that would work just fine.

However, since you're living in MVVM, it's probably more sound to use the view model's change-notifying properties as the **Single Source Of Truth** for this screen. The user control writes to this property, and the parent view reads from it, simple as that.

Rule of thumb: if more than one view-level component needs access to a property, bind both of them to the view model, not to each other.

Comment: Wouldn't the user control (this is used by other views) be tightly coupled to the parent in this case?

Comment: Keep reading, my second paragraph tells you not to do that. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.  If the user control needs to bind to a property of parent's view model, that user control must know about the parent, right?

Comment: Not necessarily; set the `DataContext` of the user control to the view model. Then you can do `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path}">` inside the user control.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  This combined with your comment on the question helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

A property can be the target of only one binding, but it can be the source (i.e. where the value "comes from") of as many bindings as you want... So yes, you can bind a property of the parent view to the `Path` property of the `UserControl`.

Comment: What enforces that it can be the target of only one? Would you get an error if that occurred?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs wow, I wrote that 8 years ago, I don't really remember... I think you get an exception. (for a dependency property, not for a normal CLR property)

Comment: I thought it was a longshot, my memory wouldn't be that good either. :) Thanks for taking a moment to w/b.

Comment: @StayOnTarget w/b?

Comment: @Clonkex sorry - "write back"